# Where was Joseph when Mary visited Jesus on the cross?

Tags: history, virgin-mary, crucifixion, joseph-husband-of-mary

Not much was mentioned about Jesus's foster-father. Mary visited Jesus, but where was Joseph at when Jesus was being crucified?